# Fetch is Undefined in Component when Mocking API Error Response with Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am testing a component that uses a `useEffect` hook that fetches data from an API, updates state and then builds out the component. I've mocked the API response successfully for several tests using [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64818305/simple-fetch-mock-using-typescript-and-jest) as an example. I am now trying to write a test where I mock a returned error from the API. I'm getting an error stating `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` for `fetch`. I'm trying to use the same example but with no luck.

My successful fetch mock with test data looks like:

```
global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() =>
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve(successMockData),
  })
)
```

My attempted mock error response currently looks like:

```
global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
  Promise.resolve({
    status: 400,
    json: () => Promise.resolve({ success: false, error: 'Something bad happened' }),
  })
})
```

The error that I get when running the test is:
[image]

If I reject the promise, I still get the same error but get the thrown exception with it too:

```
global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
  Promise.reject({
    status: 400,
    json: () => Promise.resolve({ success: false, error: 'Something bad happened' }),
  })
})
```

[image]

The API uses a NextApiResponse and looks like this:

```
try {
  // Query data from database
  const data = methodThatGetsDataFromDatabase()

  return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: data })
} catch (error) {
  return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: error.message })
}
```

I've been working at this for a long time and have about worn Google out looking for answers. I just can't figure out why `fetch` is undefined rather than returning the promise. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference I found is that, your successful fetch mock actually returns the Promise.

But the failing fetch mock is not returning -- notice the subtle addition of curly braces around that Promise. Can you check this without that curly brackets?

```
global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => 
  Promise.resolve({
    status: 400,
    json: () => Promise.resolve({ success: false, error: 'Something bad happened' }),
  })
)
```

Comment: I was definitely looking at this code for to long because that was the issue. So simple... Always helps to get another set of eyes on it! Thanks so much!

Comment: Oh man I'd been struggling with the same issue and looked far and wide for an answer... only to realize it was this. Lifesaver.